# Does GraphQL take Int as enum

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I was trying to create an enum type with Int value in GraphQL schema but failed. I might miss something in the doc. Anyone has any idea about how to implement Int value in the enum type like below?

```
enum IntValue {
  1
  2
  3
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could declare something like

```
enum IntValue { _1 _2 _3 }
enum IntName { ONE TWO THREE }
```

but in both cases those enumerated values would be different from the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`.

You can't declare something that looks like an enum but contains actual numbers.  In the [specification](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Enums), an [EnumTypeDefinition](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#EnumTypeDefinition) contains a list of [EnumValueDefinition](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#EnumValueDefinition), each of which contains a single [EnumValue](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#EnumValue); each [value](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Enum-Value) is

> *Name* but not `true` or `false` or `null`

and finally a [Name](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#Name) must begin with an underscore or a ASCII letter.